# valgrind OS X 10.10.2 installation failure (with yet another "no mach_vm.defs")

Tags: macos, valgrind

1) Xcode 6.3 is installed (though not in use)

2) something else that failed:
sudo ln -sv/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include 
Password:

ln: ./include: File exists

3) another tip calls for downloading files to "usr/include/mach" from Apple. I'm rather a newbie with OS X generally -- could that possibility be described a bit more (especially since "cd /usr.include/mach" fails)?

4) Any other suggestions? Please! (with an "impossible" uninitialized variable, I desperately need valgrind!).

Answer (score 0):

Apple now packages certain tools separately, these are found in the Command Line Tools package.

Follow these steps to install the package on modern OS X, when Xcode is already installed:

```
xcode-select --install
# Prompt will ask whether you want to install the CLT.
# Afterwards, confirm installation with
xcode-select -p
# You should see: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```